# How to avoid repeatedly use the new statement to instantiate a class?

Tags: globals, oop

I have a Class with a lot of variables.
To get a variable, I have to write this line in each function:

```
$x = new MY_Class();
```

I guess there has to be another way?

I tried:

```
function my_data(){
global $x;
$x = new MY_Class();
return apply_filters( 'my_data', $x )
}
```

Then, I tried to use `$x->var` in other functions that need the variables, but it doesn't work.

How can I make the `global $x` and its variables accessable by other functions? Thanks!

Comment: This is technically not a WordPress question, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

The way you've done it above should work. Once a variable is declared in global scope, it should be globally available (of course, your functions still need to declare it as a global: `global $x;`). You could also use the `$GLOBALS` superglobal variable:

```
global $x;
$x->var;
```

is the same as

```
$GLOBALS['x']->var;
```

I personally would use a static variable in your function:

```
function my_data(){
  static $data = null;
  if(null === $data)
    $data = new MY_Class();
  return $data;
}
```

Then anywhere in your code, you could just write `$vars = my_data();` and have the one instantiation of your class.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks, John! When I use global $x; $x->var ... in other functions, it doesn't work. instead, I have to use $v=my_data(), then, the $v->var works.